# In Ruby on Rails, how do I format a date with the "th" suffix, as in, "Sun Oct 5th"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I want to display dates in the format: short day of week, short month, day of month without leading zero but including "th", "st", "nd", or "rd" suffix.

For example, the day this question was asked would display "Thu Oct 2nd".

I'm using Ruby 1.8.7, and [Time.strftime](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Time.html#method-i-strftime) just doesn't seem to do this.  I'd prefer a standard library if one exists.

Comment: You might want to use the word "suffix" in your question or title to make this easier to find for other people.  I'm not sure if there's another word for this when talking about dates.

Comment: Excellent question. I was thinking the same thing only a couple of days ago - very helpful.

Answer (score 300, accepted):

Use the ordinalize method from 'active_support'.

```
>> time = Time.new
=> Fri Oct 03 01:24:48 +0100 2008
>> time.strftime("%a %b #{time.day.ordinalize}")
=> "Fri Oct 3rd"
```

Note, if you are using IRB with Ruby 2.0, you must first run:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/integer/inflections'
```

Comment: Just note this isn't in the standard library.

Answer (score 112):

You can use active_support's ordinalize helper method on numbers.

```
>> 3.ordinalize
=> "3rd"
>> 2.ordinalize
=> "2nd"
>> 1.ordinalize
=> "1st"
```

Comment: It's 2020 and it's still things like this that make me love Rails.

Answer (score 34):

Taking Patrick McKenzie's answer just a bit further, you could create a new file in your `config/initializers` directory called `date_format.rb` (or whatever you want) and put this in it:

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(
  my_date: lambda { |time| time.strftime("%a, %b #{time.day.ordinalize}") }
)
```

Then in your view code you can format any date simply by assigning it your new date format:

```
My Date: <%= h some_date.to_s(:my_date) %>
```

It's simple, it works, and is easy to build on.  Just add more format lines in the date_format.rb file for each of your different date formats.  Here is a more fleshed out example.

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(
   datetime_military: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',
   datetime:          '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M%P',
   time:              '%I:%M%P',
   time_military:     '%H:%M%P',
   datetime_short:    '%m/%d %I:%M',
   due_date: lambda { |time| time.strftime("%a, %b #{time.day.ordinalize}") }
)
```

Comment: Nice answer. For Rails 3, ActiveSupport has changed quite a bit, so the following is the equivalent: `Time::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(:my_date => lambda { |time| time.strftime("%a, %b #{ActiveSupport::Inflector.ordinalize(time.day)}") })`

Comment: Gotta love Rails :)

Answer (score 11):

```
>> require 'activesupport'
=> []
>> t = Time.now
=> Thu Oct 02 17:28:37 -0700 2008
>> formatted = "#{t.strftime("%a %b")} #{t.day.ordinalize}"
=> "Thu Oct 2nd"
```

Answer (score 7):

### Create your own `%o` format.

#### Initializer

**`config/initializers/srtftime.rb`**

```
module StrftimeOrdinal
  def self.included( base )
    base.class_eval do
      alias_method :old_strftime, :strftime
      def strftime( format )
        old_strftime format.gsub( "%o", day.ordinalize )
      end
    end
  end
end

[ Time, Date, DateTime ].each{ |c| c.send :include, StrftimeOrdinal }
```

#### Usage

```
Time.new( 2018, 10, 2 ).strftime( "%a %b %o" )
=> "Tue Oct 2nd"
```

You can use this with `Date` and `DateTime` as well:

```
DateTime.new( 2018, 10, 2 ).strftime( "%a %b %o" )
=> "Tue Oct 2nd"

Date.new( 2018, 10, 2 ).strftime( "%a %b %o" )
=> "Tue Oct 2nd"
```

Comment: Not sure if this is documented. I can't seem to find any record of it but we're using it in our code base so must have found it somewhere.

Comment: I'm not able to get this to work on 2.6.3. Maybe it was in an older version of Ruby? Or maybe someone monkey patched `Time` in your project?

Comment: @kcdragon Wow, you were absolutely right. Searched the codebase and found that my old buddy Chuck Bergeron added this initializer nearly 7 years ago. Regardless, I still find this very useful so I've updated the answer with how to implement it like we have it in CNTRAL.

Comment: These comments are hilarious!

Answer (score 7):

Although Jonathan Tran did say he was looking for the abbreviated day of the week first followed by the abbreviated month, I think it might be useful for people who end up here to know that Rails has out-of-the-box support for the more commonly usable long month, ordinalized day integer, followed by the year, as in `June 1st, 2018`.

It can be easily achieved with:

```
Time.current.to_date.to_s(:long_ordinal)
=> "January 26th, 2019"
```

Or:

```
Date.current.to_s(:long_ordinal)
=> "January 26th, 2019"
```

You can stick to a time instance if you wish as well:

```
Time.current.to_s(:long_ordinal)
=> "January 26th, 2019 04:21"
```

You can find more formats and context on how to create a custom one in the [Rails API docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#DATE_FORMATS).

Answer (score 6):

I like Bartosz's answer, but hey, since this is Rails we're talking about, let's take it one step up in devious.  (Edit: Although I was going to just monkeypatch the following method, turns out there is a cleaner way.)

`DateTime` instances have a `to_formatted_s` method supplied by ActiveSupport, which takes a single symbol as a parameter and, if that symbol is recognized as a valid predefined format, returns a String with the appropriate formatting.

Those symbols are defined by `Time::DATE_FORMATS`, which is a hash of symbols to either strings for the standard formatting function... or procs.  Bwahaha.

```
d = DateTime.now #Examples were executed on October 3rd 2008
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:weekday_month_ordinal] = 
    lambda { |time| time.strftime("%a %b #{time.day.ordinalize}") }
d.to_formatted_s :weekday_month_ordinal #Fri Oct 3rd
```

But hey, if you can't resist the opportunity to monkeypatch, you could always give that a cleaner interface:

```
class DateTime

  Time::DATE_FORMATS[:weekday_month_ordinal] = 
      lambda { |time| time.strftime("%a %b #{time.day.ordinalize}") }

  def to_my_special_s
    to_formatted_s :weekday_month_ordinal
  end
end

DateTime.now.to_my_special_s  #Fri Oct 3rd
```