# How to get the 'th' and 'rd' on a date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
strftime('%A, %B %d')
```

Will output Monday, August 31

Any way to get it to do Monday, August 31st?

Comment: @rpflo, the term you're looking for is *ordinal suffixes* just as a not-quite-random snippet of trivia =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165170/in-ruby-on-rails-how-do-i-format-a-date-with-the-th-suffix-as-in-sun-oct-5t)
That's from an older SO post.

Comment: That's what SO is for, To give you what you can't find! :)