# Ruby DateTime format: How can I get 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime-format

First of all, it doesn't seem that the DateTime format variables are documented anywhere so a +1 to anyone who can show this to me in **rubydocs**. Second of all, when looking at the `Date.strftime` function code, I don't see anything that can let me do something like:

`Thursday, September 9th 2010`

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Only in Ruby or with ActiveSupport ?

Comment: @shingara, if you answer again with ActiveSupport, I'll +1 that as well.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You might want to [take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165170/in-ruby-on-rails-how-do-i-format-a-date-with-the-th-suffix-as-in-sun-oct-5t).

To summarize

```
time = DateTime.now
time.strftime("%A, %B #{time.day.ordinalize} %Y")
```

Note that you are running in plain Ruby (2.0) you'll need to call:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/integer/inflections'
```

Answer (score -2):

You can found all means %xx in Time documentation

http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000298

So you just need made

```
date.strftime('%A, %B %d %Y')
```

Comment: This doesn't ordinalize the number of the day (no 'st', 'nd', etc.)