# How to customize Rails localized date format?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, localization

I am overriding a view from a Rails engine that has this code:

```
<%= l(item.publish_date, :format => :long) %>
```

The format of this becomes:

```
July 17, 2012 23:27
```

I would like to change this so that the date looks more like:

```
July 17th, 2012  # I don't even really want the time
```

However, I am completely new to how Rails localization works so I don't know how to find the documentation on how to customize this date format. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [guide here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats) for details but you can specify a format in your yml

```
# config/locales/pirate.yml
pirate:
  time:
    formats:
      short: "arrrround %H'ish"
```

A good website that helps with that is [goodstrftime](http://www.foragoodstrftime.com/). It will show you a preview of what your specified format will look like.

For example:

```
%B %d, %Y

July 18, 2012
```

Use active supports [ordinalize method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165170/in-ruby-on-rails-how-do-i-format-a-date-with-the-th-suffix-as-in-sun-oct-5) to get the 'st', 'rd', 'th' suffixes.

Comment: hmm...I'm not quite sure how to use the ordinalize method in the Yaml config file, but it's not worth my effort to figure it out right now. Thanks for the answer and links!

Comment: yeah i'm not sure about ordinalize in yml either :)