# How do I format a date with the “th” suffix, on en.yml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I wanted to add the 'th', 'nd' suffix to my date. This question solve a part of the problem : [In Ruby on Rails, how do I format a date with the "th" suffix, as in, "Sun Oct 5th"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165170/in-ruby-on-rails-how-do-i-format-a-date-with-the-th-suffix-as-in-sun-oct-5)

But I need to add it in /config/en.yml . How o do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the string to the locale

```
en:
  foo: "it is the %{day} of %{month} today"

I18n.t('foo', day: Date.today.day.ordinalize, month: Date::MONTHNAMES[Date.today.month] )
```