# Formatting time in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to format my time to have something like this `Feb, 10th`
I got everything, except the `th` part in the ending of date. Is there any method or helper that could help me to achieve such thing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165170/in-ruby-on-rails-how-do-i-format-a-date-with-the-th-suffix-as-in-sun-oct-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can look at the `ordinalize` method.  One easy way to get the strftime time format is http://strftimer.com/

```
>> 10.ordinalize # 10th
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [stamp](https://github.com/jeremyw/stamp) gem.

Here is my console output using stamp:

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > date = Date.new(2013, 1, 1)
=> Tue, 01 Jan 2013 
1.9.3p194 :002 > date.stamp("Feb, 10th")
=> "Jan, 1st" 
1.9.3p194 :003 > date = Date.new(2013, 2, 25)
=> Mon, 25 Feb 2013 
1.9.3p194 :004 > date.stamp("Jan, 1st")
=> "Feb, 25th"
```

Cheers !! :-)

Comment: `> date.stamp("Feb, 10th") # ⇒ "Jan, 1st"` looks promising :-)

Comment: yes, I have been using this, and above all, its very simple. It doesnt require any manipulation on dates. Just specify the output format you need.

Comment: Hmmm… In my galaxy `Feb, 10th` is definitely not a _“happy new year”_ day.

Comment: i think you misunderstood this, Feb, 10th is just the format you want any date to be displayed.

Comment: Ah… Yeah, sorry, you’re right, I misunderstood that.