# converting a date in ruby to a customised format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am looking for a method where I can convert a date into more of a human readable format... for example:

12/02/2013 can be converted to "2nd December 2013"
12/03/2013 should be converted to "3rd December 2013"
11/27/2013 can be converted to "27th November 2013"

Is any function in Ruby/Rails readily available to use or I have to write on my own something to handle "st","nd","rd" and "th" besides date numbers ?

Comment: check this http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165170/in-ruby-on-rails-how-do-i-format-a-date-with-the-th-suffix-as-in-sun-oct-5

Comment: Thanks, i scanned strftime() but cannot find anything per my needs. I am able to get this which can help me to get my formatted date, I can use ordinalize function after parsing date

Comment: @Kush if you dont get any other better answer please do accept as answer :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try this

```
t = Time.now()
t.strftime("#{t.day.ordinalize} %B %Y")
```

It will result in

```
27th November 2013
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `strftime` function (which is available in several laguages) in order to format times and dates.

In your case, with minimal effort you can achieve some pretty good results:

```
Time.now.strftime("%e %b %Y") #=> "27 Nov 2013"
```

For ordinalization, write a custom function or use Rails' `ordinalize` (as suggested before).

Here's the source:

```
def ordinalize(number)
  if (11..13).include?(number.to_i.abs % 100)
    "#{number}th"
  else
    case number.to_i.abs % 10
      when 1; "#{number}st"
      when 2; "#{number}nd"
      when 3; "#{number}rd"
      else    "#{number}th"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use : Time.now.strftime("%a %B %d, %Y")

```
=> "Wed November 15, 2013"

==> today = Time.now
==> today = today.strftime("%a %B #{t.day.ordinalize}, %Y")
==> "Wed November 27th, 2013"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this often, then the stamp gem is very useful -https://github.com/jeremyw/stamp

It allows you to do things like:

```
date = Date.new(2011, 6, 9)
date.stamp("Sunday, May 1, 2000")   #=> "Thursday, June 9, 2011"
date.stamp("Sun Aug 5")             #=> "Thu Jun 9"
date.stamp("12/31/99")              #=> "06/09/11"
date.stamp("DOB: 12/31/2000")       #=> "DOB: 06/09/2011"
date.stamp("November 5th")          #=> "June 9th"
date.stamp("1st of Jan")            #=> "9th of Jun"
```