# Add st, nd, rd, or th to date (ordinalize)

Tags: ruby

I am hoping to ordinalize a date I have created. This is the code I have that outputs the date.

```
Date.parse(day).strftime "%B %e (%A)"
#outputs => October 8 (Wednesday)
```

I would like to change it so that it outputs like the following:

October 8th (Wednesday)

Ive looked at this, but can't seem to get it right: [In Ruby on Rails, how do I format a date with the "th" suffix, as in, "Sun Oct 5th"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165170/in-ruby-on-rails-how-do-i-format-a-date-with-the-th-suffix-as-in-sun-oct-5)

Any ideas on how this might be done? Thanks!

Comment: [Here is the Google search](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=rails+date+th+st&oq=rails+date+th+st&aqs=chrome..69i57.5419j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8) I did for you.. Enjoy! :-)

Comment: Yes.. Then what is stopping you ?

Comment: I tried inserting the .ordinalize inside of the `"%B %e (%A)"`, but that didnt help

Comment: You can change the format string as per the need... Wouldn't you ?

Comment: Did you install `active_support` Gem ?

Comment: probably not, ill give that a shot

Comment: You have to install the Gem, if you are not in _Rails_ environment..