# Adding "st,nd,rd,th" to a date in Ruby

Tags: ruby, date, time, strftime

Currently, I am making a program that detects a date in an HTML source and compares it to the current date.

While thinking out my code. I realized that I've run into a little problem. The HTML I'm scraping and comparing uses a format like this "December 23rd, 2014". What I have so far will not be able to compare to that.

My code that prints current date does not add a "st,nd,rd, or th" to the day of the month.

```
time = Time.new
puts time.strftime("%B %d, %Y")
```

Can anyone find a solution for this?

Comment: @mdesantis I disagree. That's Rails-specific, this is general Ruby.

Comment: Good point, so duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165170/in-ruby-on-rails-how-do-i-format-a-date-with-the-th-suffix-as-in-sun-oct-5

Comment: Seeing how I used the " #{time.day.ordinalize} and it gave me an error 

"undefined method 'ordinalize' for 30:Fixnum (NoMethodError)"
It's safe to say this is not a valid solution.

Comment: Can you add info to your question about how you're comparing the existing HTML (that has "st", "nd", etc.) versus your code? It is very easy to skip the "st", "nd", etc. in comparisons if you're using typical pattern matching.