# Ruby date time parse to get 'th'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got date as string `'2020-02-10 8,00'` which I want to convert into `Monday, 10th of February`. I'm aware of [this old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165170/in-ruby-on-rails-how-do-i-format-a-date-with-the-th-suffix-as-in-sun-oct-5) topic however I cannot find (or use) any related information.

All I have is just parsed string to date - `Date.parse '2020-02-10 8,00'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are halfway there! `Date.parse '2020-02-10 8,00'` produces a ruby Date object, as you have noted. You now have to apply `strftime`. However `strftime` doesn't have any ordinalization so that piece has to be done manually.

```rb
date = Date.parse('2020-02-10 8,00')

date.strftime("%A, #{date.day.ordinalize} of %B") #=> Monday, 10th of February
```

the `ordinalize` method is provided by ActiveSupport.

If this format will be used multiple times in your app, you may wish to add an app-wide format:

```rb
# in config/initializers/time_formats.rb
Date::DATE_FORMATS(:ordinalized_day) = lambda{|date| date.strftime("%A, #{date.day.ordinalize} of %B")}


# anywhere in the app
Date.today.to_formatted_s(:ordinalized_day)
```